# Failure to read from Pubsub when running Dataflow job template

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I'm using the Templates feature to store a Dataflow job template in GCS and run it in multiple GCP projects. This works fine when I hardcode the Pubsub subscriptions to read from, but I need to be able to set those at execution time – specifically, I need to be able to set the GCP project id that the subscriptions are in, i.e. set `projects/<project>/subscriptions/my-sub` at execution time.

I've tried to use a ValueProvider on the CLI:

```
@Description("The GCP project to run the pipeline in")
def getProjectId: ValueProvider[String]
def setProjectId(value: ValueProvider[String])
```

I can see in the monitoring UI that the project id is set correctly when I run the job.

I then map the project id to my various subscriptions using NestedValueProvider:

```
val function = new SerializableFunction[String, String] {
  override def apply(value: String): String = s"projects/$value/subscriptions/my-sub"
}

NestedValueProvider.of[String, String](projectIdProvider, function)
```

The `PubsubIO.Read.subscription` method accepts the ValueProvider, but when I run the job I get this error in the logs and no messages are being read:

```
construct-template-5-05010625-b4a3-harness-03lg Update range task for 8042011276981323245 returned error status, will be retried as necessary: INVALID_ARGUMENT: Http(400) Bad Request
```

The Stackdriver log message says that this error occurs at `work_service_client.cc:680`

Comment: What's the job ID?

Comment: @jkff: 2017-05-02_02_01_06-2205859387558429271

Comment: Looking at your pipeline, it appears that you are attempting to read from the subscription that is just the name of your project, which is not a valid subscription name. You need to make sure the subscription value passed to PubsubIO.Read.subscription is in the format "projects/project/subscriptions/sub" not just "project", which is the current state of 2017-05-02_02_01_06-2205859387558429271

Comment: Is there a way for me to inspect that myself? I'm mapping the project id to a subscription path, so something must be going wrong...

Comment: We're adding a better error message.